# PHP Error Call to undefined function RecordCount()

Tags: prepared-statement, php

I'm fairly new to PHP and have been trying to make a simple login using PHP PDO. When I try and login it keeps throwing this error -  Call to undefined function RecordCount(). My searching has provided no insight as to why this is happening. My code is below. Any insight into where to look or why this is happening would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
     <?php
        include_once '../utils/dbcon.php';

        $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users where username = ? AND password = ?");

if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['username'],$_GET['password'])))
 {


   if ($stmt.RecordCount())
       {

        echo "record found";
       } 
   elseif(!$stmt.RecordCount())
           {
       echo "No records found";
       }

 }  


        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
$stmt.RecordCount()
```

should be

```
$stmt->RecordCount()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Now it's throwing - Call to undefined method PDOStatement::RecordCount(). I changed the method to rowcount() and it seems to be working now. I appreciate the help!